# How can i prevent leaflet from dragging the map to fit marker popups?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

currently we are working on a leaflet-project with gmaps and i´ve got a little problem .

After adding multiple markers (with a popup each) we want to open them all.

To do so, i´m using the following peace of code:

```
L.Map = L.Map.extend({
    openPopup: function(popup) {
    //        this.closePopup(); 
    this._popup = popup;

    return this.addLayer(popup).fire('popupopen', {
        popup: this._popup
    });
    }
});
```

On pageload everything works as expected.

But here comes the fail scenario:

After `pageload` the user `zooms in` and some markers are `out of the “view area”` of the user.

few seconds later, the website loads `new position data` (for the markers) `using a rest interface`.

After position data transmitted, i currently remove all markers and recreate them at the transmitted positions and open them.

And this `marker.openPopup()` triggers, that the `map moves` so, that the `popup fits in the “view area” of the user`.

How can i `prevent leaflet to drag the map` in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the `autoPan` property? From the API: `Set it to false if you don't want the map to do panning animation to fit the opened popup.`

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup

So when creating your Popup, just pass in the option `autoPan: false`

Comment: omg... I was always thinking it´s a bug, which was induced by the `openAllPopUp`-Hack. Never thought of a simple option in the popUp-object.. Thank yoU!