# Leaflet: How do I prevent map panning to last drawn marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I have a basic Leaflet map where I need to draw several markers and lines on. How do I prevent the map from panning to the last drawn object?

I've read about setting `autopan : False` for popups from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712637/how-can-i-prevent-leaflet-from-dragging-the-map-to-fit-marker-popups).

Can the `autopan : false` option work for leaflet markers?

Answer (score 2):

Without you supplying any code, it's hard to say. Normally (per default) it doesn't pan to a new marker. Take this code for example:

```
// HTML
<button onclick="setMarker()">Draw marker on Paris</button>
<div id="map"></div>

// Default map
var map = L.map('map', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0,
    'layers': [
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
        })
    ]
});

// Fit map to view London
map.fitBounds([
    [51.286839, -0.510350],
    [51.692322, 0.334030]
]);

// Function to draw marker on Paris
function setMarker () {
    L.marker([48.8567, 2.3508]).addTo(map);
}
```

It sets the map to fit London and when you click the button, it draws a marker on Paris but the map doesn't pan. If you're seeing panning behaviour on your map, it must be something else you're doing to your map. Here you can test it for yourself:

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/C2qblP?p=preview

Comment: It seems the solution was to give the Map a center. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right (anymore?), creating a map and marker as per the leaflet tutorial, using default options, the map will autopan to center a newly added marker, as well as any time you move the marker by using setLatLng (and, confusingly, setting `autoPan: false` as marker option does not stop that from happening either).